# Haskell function won't work, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: haskell

Hi i am trying to remove all multiples of m from a list (ex [2..100])

my Code:

```
crossOut :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
crossOut n ns = [ x | x <- ns , x /= (n*x)]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`x /= (n*x)` tests if `x` is `n` times itself, which isn't going to work. Try `` x `mod` n /= 0 `` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Your function, when read in English, would sound like: "any x in ns, where x does not equal n times x, for some input n". Aside from n = 1, this will always be true, and so no elements will be removed.